# How do I import configurable products? csv?

Tags: configurable-product, import, csv, simple-product

I have created a `.csv` file and then created a profile to import **simple products** which works absolutely fine.

However when I create a **configurable product**, it does not associate the simple products to the configurable products?

Comment: I have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

The most usable way is to build a configurable in the backend, export it and look at it. Every Other approach is somewhat difficult to get the head arround.

Sadly i only have good documentation in german at hands, but the structure you need could be extracted from those sources:
http://www.webguys.de/magento/turchen-19-produktimport-mit-der-importexport-schnittstelle/
http://de.meet-magento.com/wp-content/uploads/review/ImportExport_Vinai.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What I have done is created a configurable product, exported the information into a CSV and then added simple products to this and also used the associated column, but unfortunately this does not seem to work and link the products together

Comment: The products get added into the back end of magento but do not link together. For example, 1 configurable product is created and 2 simple products, but when I click on the configurable product I have to click on 'Size' for example and then manually associate the products to it

Comment: @lukebrown there should also be columns starting with `_super`. Please find more details in my answer.

Comment: That sound a lot like you are missing _supre_attribute_code because that is specifying the attributes that are used to configure the product.

Comment: The english translation of that link is available at http://www.integer-net.com/2012/04/04/importing-products-with-the-import-export-interface/.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Nils says, the best way is to first create one configurable product with associated simple products in the admin panel manually and then do an export using the export function from `System > Import/Export > Export`. By doing this you will have a `.csv` file that is fully compatible with your Magento version.

When closely examining the file you should also see some specific columns for configurable products, for instance:

`_super_products_sku`,
`_super_attribute_code`,
`_super_attribute_option`, and
`_super_attribute_price_corr`

You will need to enter the correct data for each configurable product in those columns. If you do this the right way then the simple products should be associated to the configurable products automatically.

Comment: Thank you for the information? I do not have any 'Super' columns on my CSV! Are these all I have to add onto my spreadsheet? Thanks

Comment: I think those are all. But I'm wondering why you don't have them in your export `.csv` file. What Magento version are you using? This may be different for older versions, I don't know. Please also read [this info](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/importing-configurable-products) carefully. It is for Magento Go but also applies to CE.

Comment: @lukebrown If you don't have the _super fields in your export you may be using the Dataflow export which doesn't include these columns. Make sure to use the `System > Import/Export > Export` feature to see the correct columns.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this article with guide on how to import configurable product and simple product in Magento](http://magentoexplorer.com/how-to-csv-import-simple-and-configurable-magento-product), you can use Migami or some 3rd party Magento extension for configurable product import in Magento
Magmi is the most powerful tool to import both simple and configurable product in Magento.
If you want to Migami, click on this link to download Migami: http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/

Answer (score 0):

You should try [Magmi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/). I think it is the most powerful import tool. You can import configurable products and associate simple products: http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Configurable_Item_processor

Answer (score 0):

For importing the configurable product along with its associated (simple) product. In the product CSV you will have to add extra attribute which are not mentioned in above comments. Also after exporting CSV magento will not add the attributes in CSV.

In the End of CSV file add these attributes these two attributes:

- configurable_attributess
- simples_skus

**Uses of the attributes:**

- configurable_attributes : If you have size attribute then for all simple products add the Size in this attribute column and for configurable product add name size, like the screen shot below:
  [image]
- simples_skus: In the attribute column left all the simple product blank and for configurable product add all the simple sku's separated by comma. same as the screen shot below:
  [image]

Now when the the CSV will uploaded the configurable product will get uploaded with its configurable option(color, size etc) and all the associated(simple) products will be added.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This document helped me to execute this import.

https://www.lexiconn.com/blog/2016/01/magento-2-import-configurable-products/