# after configurable product being imported, on editing it shows attributes to make configurable

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, import, csv

I have successfully imported a configurable product with all it's simple products. But on editing the configurable product from backend, it shows global attributes to make configurable product like the first time i'm creating.

Below is the screenshot of what i see on editing the already imported product.

[image]

Comment: Please note this questions is already asked at http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96298/after-configurable-product-being-imported-on-editing-it-shows-attributes-to-mak but there were no answers

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at this topic: [How do I import configurable products? csv?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/48373/how-do-i-import-configurable-products-csv). I think the answer by Nils Preuß and the comments can be pretty helpful.

Comment: thanks @Arjen, Problem Resolved, I missed to save Attribute which is being used for configurable products